# (Lyx) Is there an alternative to \bigskip?

Tags: lyx

I use \bigskip to create a blank line between two lines, I need this when I write down two different definition for example. Unfortunately you can't insert a blank line manually in Lyx, at least I didn't find that. Then I always used \bigskip, but \bigskip makes a space like about two lines. But I only want a spacing of one line, does anyone have a tip?

[image: L]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try `\smallskip` or `\medskip`.

Comment: You should not be adding space at all. The space above a lemma environment should be set as part of its definition so it is consistent, not relying on space being added in each instance.

Comment: Thanks David, but what exactly do you mean? I'm afraid I did not understand?

Comment: See `\theorempreskipamount` and `\theorempostskipamount` (page 3).

Comment: LaTeX (and so LyX) is not designed to do the layout work manually, quite the opposite, and that's why LyX doesn't let you put more than a normal space or just a blank line.  It is  not your work fix the spaces after each word or  paragraph.  If you don't like the result, go to Document → Setting ... and set in the preamble how things should will look , but it's a not good idea insert here and there low level formatting commands to try to "fix" that settings.